# Failed to enable the 'dataready' Accept Filter

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd, httpd

I'm not sure why, but I'm getting this warning when I start my apache...

```
su-3.2# /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
[Wed Sep 23 13:40:42 2009] [warn] (2)No such file or directory: Failed to enable the 'dataready' Accept Filter
su-3.2# grep accf /boot/loader.conf 
accf_data_load="YES"
accf_http_load="YES"
su-3.2# kldstat | grep accf
 3    1 0xffffffff80ce9000 7d0      accf_data.ko
 4    1 0xffffffff80cea000 14d8     accf_http.ko
su-3.2# uname -a
FreeBSD dd.alexus.org 7.2-RELEASE-p1 FreeBSD 7.2-RELEASE-p1 #7: Sat Jun 27 02:42:30 UTC 2009     alexus@dd.alexus.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
su-3.2#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your apache httpd is not looking for the `httpready` Accept Filter, it is looking for **dataready** filter. I have no idea why. (Wild guess is that your are using `mod_ftp`.)

try this:

```
kldload accf_data.ko
```

or this in loader.conf:

```
accf_data_load="YES"
```

Comment: -bash-3.2# ./bin/httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_authn_file.c
  mod_authn_default.c
  mod_authz_host.c
  mod_authz_groupfile.c
  mod_authz_user.c
  mod_authz_default.c
  mod_auth_basic.c
  mod_include.c
  mod_filter.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_env.c
  mod_setenvif.c
  mod_version.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_mime.c
  mod_status.c
  mod_autoindex.c
  mod_asis.c
  mod_cgi.c
  mod_negotiation.c
  mod_dir.c
  mod_actions.c
  mod_userdir.c
  mod_alias.c
  mod_so.c
-bash-3.2#

Comment: I recommend not using the accept filtering in FreeBSD at this time.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone's information, the reason Apache looks for the dataready filter in addition to the httpready filter is because SSL connections cannot be handled with the httpready filter.  The dataready filter almost gives the same level of "avoiding-kernel-mode-shifting" benefits to an HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `accf_data_load="YES"` in your loader.conf as well?

Comment: yes, I put that few days ago and I just restarted my box, so it seems like it's working now...