# Apache: Failed to enable the 'httpready' Accept Filter

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd

So kernel modules are loaded!! what goes on??

```
accf_http_load="YES"
accf_data_load="YES"
```

trying to load ...

```
dev# kldload accf_data.ko
kldload: can't load accf_data.ko: File exists
```

and still having this errors

```
[Fri Aug 26 09:23:31 2011] [warn] (22)Invalid argument: Failed to enable the 'httpready' Accept Filter
[Fri Aug 26 09:23:31 2011] [warn] (22)Invalid argument: Failed to enable the 'dataready' Accept Filter
```

why nobody answers to this question [httpready problem on Apache httpd restart on FreeBSD?](https://serverfault.com/questions/72490/httpready-problem-on-apache-httpd-restart-on-freebsd) !!! Same question as mine! It's a new bug in freebsd or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok issue is solved.

```
dev# cat /boot/defaults/loader.conf | grep accf
accf_data_load="NO"     # Wait for data accept filter
accf_dns_load="NO"      # Wait for full DNS request accept filter
accf_http_load="NO"     # Wait for full HTTP request accept filter

dev# cat /etc/rc.conf | grep apache22
apache22_http_accept_enable="NO"
apache22_enable="YES"
```

I don't know since when this apache22_http_accept_enable param appeared in rc.conf but this should be set to NO, and if you wont add any accept filter so no warnings won't be displayed. Situation was different in the past. Usually if you won't load accept filter then warning will appear every time you start apache.. now it's different..

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37863) indicate that the problem only occurs on apachectl restart or apachectl graceful?  Can't you workaround it with an apachectl stop, then an apachectl start until the issue is fixed at the apache level?